# Difference between new xxxBorder() and Borderfactory method?

Tags: java, swing, border, titled-border

What is the difference between

```
setBorder(new TitledBorder(""));
```

and

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
```

and which advantages/disadvantages do they have?

Comment: I think there is no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BorderFactory` actually might not create new instances each time you call it, but return a reference to an existing one, therefore saving some resources. See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html).

You can also check out the [actual implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/BorderFactory.java) if you really want to know what's going on inside `BorderFactory` ;-)

Comment: +1 for the documentation reference(well the actual reason is for answering)

Answer (score 1):

According to *Effective Java*, **item-1: Consider static factory methods instead of constructors**. `BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("")` is static factory method which has following advantages:

1. One advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they
   have names.
2. A second advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors,
   they are not required to create a new object each time they’re invoked.
3. A third advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors,
   they can return an object of any subtype of their return type.
4. A fourth advantage of static factory methods is that they reduce the verbosity
   of creating parameterized type instances.

For details descriptions, go through the Book.

Comment: The item is put for letting us know to think while implementing such. But with already implemented class, we must know why actually they were done for this specific class.